# How to solve $\underset{x \to -2^+}\lim (x+3) \frac{|x+2|}{x+2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to solve $\underset{x \to -2^+}\lim (x+3) \frac{|x+2|}{x+2}$, but I'm not sure how to approach it, since I can't change the absolute value in the numerator.

I have tried L'Hospitals Rule:

$$\underset{x \to -2^+}\lim  \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x+3)|x+2|}{\frac{d}{dx}x+2}$$

$$=\underset{x \to -2^+}\lim \frac{2x^2+9x+10}{|x+2|}$$

$$=\underset{x \to -2^+}\lim \frac{(2x+5)(x+2)}{|x+2|}$$

However, I'm not sure where to go from this point.

How can I solve this limit?

Comment: For $x>-2$, $|x+2|=x+2$.

Comment: @egreg does that mean I should just treat $|x-2|$ as $(x+2)$?

Comment: Yes, because you only care about values of $x$ which are bigger than $-2$. You are computing only the one sided limit.

Comment: One does not "solve" limits; rather, one *finds* or *evaluates* them (if they exist at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the limit for $x\to-2^+$ you're basically restricting the domain of the function to the interval $(-2,\infty)$. Over this domain, $|x+2|=x+2$.

Thus the limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to-2^+}(x+3)\frac{x+2}{x+2}=\lim_{x\to-2^+}(x+3)=1
$$

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you were more surprised by the notation than the calculation of the limit itself, so here is a succinct presentation:

$$\Large{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)}$$

Means studying the behaviour of $f(x)$ when $x$ converges to $x_0$. This is the usual sense.

$$\Large{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^-} f(x)=\mathop{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}}_{x<x_0} f(x)}$$

Means studying the behaviour of $f(x)$ when $x$ converges to $x_0$ but while staying always below $x_0$, or if you prefer when coming from the left of $x_0$.

By extension we call it the left limit of $f$ in $x_0$.

$$\Large{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+} f(x)=\mathop{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}}_{x>x_0} f(x)}$$

Means studying the behaviour of $f(x)$ when $x$ converges to $x_0$ but while staying always above $x_0$, or if you prefer when coming from the right of $x_0$.

By extension we call it the right limit of $f$ in $x_0$.

*Note that in the usual case, $x$ can take values anywhere below or above $x_0$, a necessary and sufficient condition for the limit to exists is that both the left limit and the right limit exist and are equal.*

---

With that in consideration $x\to -2^+$ implies $x>-2$ or equivalently $x+2>0$.

Thus $|x+2|=x+2$ in this case, and we can simplify as egreg showed in his answer.